# Why child class type is not assignable to type 'this'?

Tags: typescript

i have:

```js
class A {
  parent: A;

  constructor(parent: A) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  getParent(): this { // ERROR
    return this.parent; // ERROR
  }
}
```

Error: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'this'. 'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'A'.

Why?

class `B` extends class `A`, B is subtype A.

So why `this` (as `B`, because `this` is polymorph) isn't compatible with `A`?

P.S. i know that i can use `this` for `parent` in A class, but i don't understand why it doesn't work now, for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> class `B` extends class `A`, B is subtype A.
>
> So why `this` (as `B`, because `this` is polymorph) isn't compatible with `A`?

`this` (i.e. `B`) *is* compatible with `A`. But that's not the point.

Read the error message: the error message is *not* saying that `this` is not compatible with `A`. It says that the `A` is not assignable to `this`:

> Error: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'this'. 'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'A'.

And that is correct: you cannot assign a value of type `A` to a reference of type `B`.

Roughly speaking, a value of type `V` can be assigned to a reference of type `R` if one of these conditions is true:

- `V` = `R`
- `V` <: `R`
- There exists an implicit conversion from `V` to `R`

`A` is not the same type as `this` (i.e. `B`), it is not a subtype of `this`, and there is no implicit conversion from `A` to `B`, ergo, an `A` value cannot be assigned to a `B` reference.

Now, you might ask yourself: "Where is the assignment here?" And indeed, the wording is a little confusing. You can think of the return value of `getParent()` as an invisible variable that gets assigned when the functions returns, or you can think of `return` as assigning to a "return slot" on the call stack.

Answering the question in your subject line:

> Why child class type is not assignable to type 'this'?

The answer is: a child class type *is* assignable to type 'this'. But this is *not* a child class type. It is a *parent* class type. The function and the property are even *called* `getParent()` and `parent` after all!

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's so hard, i need some time for understand it.

Would it be correct to use `parent: this;` instead of `parent: A;` in class `A`?
parent is not parent class, it's parent Node (same class) for binary tree